# Speedup MatchIt

Tags: r, performance, matching

I am running a matching procedure in R, using the MatchIt package. I use propensity score match, that is: estimate treatment selection by logit, and pick the nearest match.

The dataset is huge (4million rows), is there no way to speed it up?

To make it clear what I have done:

```
require(MatchIt)
m.out <- matchit(treatment ~ age + agesq + male + income + ..., data = data, metod = "nearest")
```

Comment: Did you find any solution elsewhere? My dataset is also ~4 million rows with 350 columns and available memory of 120 GB. It is running from past 15 hours. I am thinking the process is stuck...

Comment: At least for me, it did not stop... I just took forever to complete (30days +++). So I ended up using a resample method, and used it to convice myself that I got consisten estimates. 
Have a look at:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/index.html , which should allow paralel matching. If you a have a couple of CPU's in that computer, the speedup should be significant

Comment: Wow. 30 days... I guess I will kill it right away and start with your Matching. Do you know of any other ways of doing this by python/emr/spark/hadoop?

Comment: @androboy... The problem of finding matched grows exponetially, so 400.000 OBS was 16hours (-ish)... It was agonizing, to say the least. I think a paralel function is the way to go, I don't see why it should be (significantly) faster in, say, Python... Matching just does some checking, the actualy lifting is done in C

Comment: Hmm.. after multiple attempts with 4-8 CPUs and the same RAM, I still dont see a result with GenMatch after multiple trials each ranging from 2-7 days. Instead I get the following error and other similar errors mostly. ------------Maximization Problem.
Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection
Calls: GenMatch ... recvOneData -> recvOneData.SOCKcluster -> unserialize
Execution halted

Comment: I am now thinking of splitting the data by k-means clustering and running MatchIt - propensity score matching for each cluster in parallel and combine final matched results. I am really not sure what other problems I am going to run into...

Comment: I'm aware it's been 5 years since the last post, but did you find any solutions for this problem? We're currently running into it, so I was wondering if there's something we can do about it.

Comment: @paulochf I ended up doing grouped matching. Essentially I formed sub groups based on discrete variables (like gender , age etc.) and the used matching within each group

Comment: @Repmat Thanks! It's a great help!

Comment: For posterity: since this question was asked, `MatchIt` has been improved. It now uses C++ for matching so it is much faster and has the ability to produce a progress bar. It can be further sped up by exact matching on variables, as @Repmat did, which automatically matches within subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

I was similarly frustrated but found a solution for my case.

Essentially, I found a substantial run-time reduction by splitting the propensity score matching into 3 steps:

1. Run the regression model and append the fitted values (i.e., your propensity scores) to your data.
2. Trim your data columns down to only what you need:  i.e., the unique record identifier and the appended propensity score. I saved the trimmed data to disk (not shown), but your implementation would likely still speed up if everything is kept in memory.
3. Run matchit on the trimmed data with your propensity scores as a user-supplied distance, then join-back all the columns in your full original data.

```
library(MatchIt)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

#step 1
data$myfit <- fitted(glm(treatment ~ age + agesq + male + income + ..., data = data, family = "binomial"))

#step 2
trimmed_data <- select(data, unique_id, myfit, treatment)

#step 3
m.out <- matchit(treatment ~ unique_id, data = trimmed_data, method = "nearest", distance = trimmed_data$myfit)
matched_unique_ids_etc <- match.data(m.out, data = trimmed_data)
matched_unique_ids <- select(matched_unique_ids_etc, unique_id)
matched_data <- matched_unique_ids %>% inner_join(data)
```

The formula does not affect the nearest-neighbor matching process.

The default distance/link for matchit was glm/logit when I wrote this, so the code above is applicable to that case.